# How to link to another methods in dart comments

Tags: flutter, dart, comments, documentation

I was documenting my code and I wanted to link another method in the same file

I want to refer to that method in a comment so anyone reading my comment can directly jump to that method where my comment refers

**Method where I am documenting and I want to link to a method named** `toggleFavorite` in the same file

```
// To avoid code duplication in [toggleFavorite] method
  void _toogleFav(newStatus) {
    isFavorite = newStatus;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

This is what my toggleFavorite returns in case you need it

```
Future<void> toggleFavorite() async {
```

**What I want**

Exactly I want this word in my comment `[toggleFavorite]` to work as a link when I press this I get redirected to this method wherever it is created or used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use triple `///` and `[]` around the method

```dart
  /// To avoid code duplication in [toggleFavorite] method
  void _toogleFav(newStatus) {
    isFavorite = newStatus;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```